# C++ and XGrabKeyboard keyboard locking

Tags: c++, qt, x11, xlib

I'm trying to write small C++ program which should detect are user press any key on keyboard
or make mouse move. That program I need run on Ubuntu or Centos.
That's why for key-press detection I use X11 library.

Here is code that I googled:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <X11/Xlib.h>
    #include <X11/Xutil.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main(void)
    {
        Display * dpy = XOpenDisplay(0x0);
        XEvent ev;

        if(!dpy) return 1;

        Time t = CurrentTime;
        XGrabKeyboard(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), false, 
                           GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync,t);

        for(;;)
        {
          //XGrabKeyboard(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), false, 
          //                   GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync,t);
            XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
            if(ev.type == KeyPress)
                cout << "Key pressed" << endl;
          // XGrabKeyboard(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), false,                 
          //                      GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync,t);

        }
    }
```

It works good, but not properly for me.
It locks keyboard for input in all windows except it own program (uncommenting first and last lines in loop gave me the same result).

Maybe somebody know how can I fix it or what library I can use instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XSendEvent() helps for me. See http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSendEvent.html

```
 switch(ev.type)
    {
    case KeyPress:
        XSendEvent(display,InputFocus,False,KeyPressMask,&ev);
        break;
    case KeyRelease:
        XSendEvent(display,InputFocus,True,KeyReleaseMask,&ev);
        break;
    case ButtonPress:
        XSendEvent(display,PointerWindow,True,ButtonPressMask,&ev);
        break;
    case ButtonRelease:
        XSendEvent(display,PointerWindow,True,ButtonPressMask,&ev);
        break;
    default:

        break;
    }
```

Comment: That only works if the application is not ignoring synthesized events, like `xterm` does for security reasons.